# Simulating data for clustering using randcorr function in r

Tags: r

Good day, all. I am trying to simulate data using data the randcorr function in R. The challenge I have here is that I need to simulate a data with 2 clusters and with the following parameters mu=c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(50,0, 0, 50),2,2) using the randcorr function in R. The randcorr function doesn't allow for such addition to the function. Attached is the code I have. Any idea will be highly appreciated.

```
library(randcorr)
data= randcorr(5)
colnames(data) <- c("x1","x2", "x3", "x4", "x5")
cluster <- c(rep(1,50),rep(2,50)) # creating 2 clusters of equal length
dat1<- data.frame(data.scaled, cluster);
head(dat1)
tail(dat1)
```

Comment: this might not be what you want, but `mvtnorm` can simulate multivariate distributions http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math47/R/library/mvtnorm/html/Mvnorm.html

Comment: data is 5x5 and cluster is length 100 so they don't fit together